# Fundamental group of the sphere via triangulation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, trees, fundamental-groups, spheres

I know that the fundamental group of the sphere is zero, i.e. $\pi(S^2)=0$

I want to show this by triangulation, i.e:

1. Triangulate the sphere
2. Draw maximal tree
3. Draw maximal contractable subspace
4. Consider generators on remaining 1-simplices

Here is what happened:

I drew the following triangulation:

[image: Sphere]

I then proceeded to draw the maximal tree. But to include all vertices, and due to the imposed identifications, I found that this was just the boundary, so not a tree

[image: Tree]

So can we just conclude that since we cannot carry out the process, the fundamental group is zero? I was wondering how to do this formally -perhaps I am missing a step?

Many thanks

Comment: Actually that "boundary" marked in yellow is a tree. In a separate drawing, draw vertices a,b,c and d and then draw in the edges marked in your drawing: ad, bd and cd. This is a tree. In your drawing is doesn't look like a tree due to the identifications.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you consider the graph, how can one single vertex $d$ appear so many times? In the standard triangulation of $S^2$ you are supposed to have only $4$ vertices anyway.

[image]

The Fundamental group is generated by $m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4,m_5, m_6$.
With the relations $m_1 = m_4 = m_5 = 1$.

And, for each triangle, multiplication of the edges of the $2$ simplices i.e., the triangles of the graph (according to orientation) being equal to $1$.

For example for the triangle $adb$, we have $m_1 m_2 m_3 = 1$.

Write down these relations for all the triangles and manipulate the generators.

(For example, $m_1 = 1$ and $m_1m_2m_3 = 1$ implies $m_2m_3 = 1$. )

You will easily get that the fundamental group has to be trivial.

Comment: But the triangulation I gave is a correct triangulation right?

Comment: I have seen it in "A guide to the classification theorem for compact surfaces by Gallier and Xu

Comment: Its a correct triangulation of course. But you don't think of it as a graph like that. The graph has to be the actual graph on 4 vertices. Not some representation of the triangulation.

Comment: Well for shapes like the klein bottle and the projective plane, I typically draw 'flat' triangulations if that makes sense (using the square with identifications) and then triangulating this 2D space... So I tried to do a similar thing with sphere, I am not familiar with the 3D version...

Comment: I'm not drawing a 3D diagram. I am just drawing the graph. In a graph you don't write the same vertex 3 times like you did with $d$.

Comment: OK thanks, I think I understand your solution. I also tried to calculate the fundamental group of the cylinder which is homeomorphic to the sphere. I found that it was generated by one element, which corresponds to fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$.. so I am unsure of this discrepancy

Comment: Cylinder is homeomorphic to the sphere? !

Comment: yes, can then not be continuously deformed to one another

Comment: Well, a cylinder can be continuously deformed to a *circle* and a circle has  fundamental group equal to $\mathbb Z$. There is no discrepancy.

Comment: So to clarify, are the following correct: $\pi(Cylinder)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi(Sphere)=1$? Thank you

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @thinker though Shubhodip is talking about an infinite cylinder, of course! If you have a finite cylinder with caps on the end then that would be homeomorphic to the sphere. But when you say "cylinder" you would almost always be talking about an infinite cylinder.

Comment: @JoshuaHunt I normally think of the finite cylinder but I guess I should specify either way. Is it true that the finite and infinite cylinders both have the same fundamental group?

Comment: ^Yes. Both deformation retracts to a circle.