# How can I compute the fundamental group of a surface (Fulton Chapter 17)?

Tags: intuition, surfaces, fundamental-groups, triangulation

I'm reading the chapter 17 of Fultons Book "Algebraic topology a first course" and I somehow have some problems in understanding the triangulation of a surface and what it has to do with computing the fundamental group of a surface. I don't know if I should post the pages of the book but maybe you have it also. It would be nice if we could discuss about it and maybe if you could do some examples because for example I don't see why we need the euler equation/characteristic to say something about the fundamental group of the surface.

I really would appreciate it if someone can discuss it with me, so you don't need to write a whole explanation maybe there are some useful and clear examples where we can apply the theory and then I maybe see where I still have problems. Because we didn't discussed it in the exercise sheets.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Read about Van Kampen's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Stackexchange is not a useful platform for having discussions or conversations. It works well when you have a specific, answerable question.

Triangulating a surface gives you concrete combinatorial data to work with. If the surface is compact, the triangulation can be chosen to be finite, so you have finitely many vertices, edges and triangles you can enumerate and study.

Every path on the surface is homotopic to a path the runs along the edges, and homotopy between paths can be described by sequences of sliding along triangles. By choosing a spanning tree, you can find a set of generators for the fundamental group, and the triangles yield relations. From there, the fundamental group can be computed.

The Euler characteristic will turn out to be one of the few governing factors of the topology of the surface. That’s not supposed to be obvious from the beginning: it will emerge once you compute sufficiently many fundamental groups.

Comment: Oh okey. So but when I have a triangulation on a compact oreintable surface, we wrote something like, then the it is homeomorphic to a sphere with handles. But I quite do not understand this. So for what is this useful? And could you maybe give an example where we use the euler characteristic to compute the fundamental group?

Comment: I can’t speak to the paragraphs you’re referring to, and it’s quite hard to follow your sentences. It is not obvious that a compact orientable surface is a sphere with handles, and I don’t know if Fulton goes to the lengths of proving it.

Comment: See an example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778421/fundamental-group-of-the-sphere-via-triangulation

Comment: thanks for the example could you explain how you get to this triangulation of a sphere for example

Comment: Do you understand that the surface of a tetrahedron is homeomorphic to a sphere? If not, you should take several steps back and start there before tackling the fundamental group of surfaces.

Comment: so I mean geometrically I can pull all the vertices out and then I get a deformation retract to a sphere right?

Comment: @aprozz, like I said this isn’t a useful site for having private tutoring sessions. I don’t know what you know, what you don’t know, what you’re trying to learn and how you can be helped. This isn’t the place for that.

Comment: hmm okey thats sad... but then what would you recommend?

Comment: Again, I can’t say since I’ve no idea what your background is and what you’re trying to do. The vast majority of people learn those things in college. Some find communities, maybe on Discord, or AoPS, or Brilliant, or Coursera. I really don’t know.

Comment: I am in a mathematics topology course and unfortunately we make algebraic topology. I have some problems in seeing why this topic with triangulations is useful and I wanted to ask some questions, but since I don't know where to start I thought that in a discussion it would be easier. But as you said here we cant have a discussion. So I mean if I post an exercise here so that someone can correct it, it gets closed because it's a duplicate. If I ask something without informations because I don't understand it it also gets closed. And we also don't can have a discussion here...thats sad because I

Comment: Like this site really